# EF 4.1 Code First multiple Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a certain code-first relationship.  I have three entities: Group, User, GroupPermission.  The GroupPermission entity holds information about permissions that relate to a group.  There are three permissions: leader, editor, user.  The GroupPermission table should include the primary key Id and the name of the permission.  Then I want a relationship table that looks something like this: Id - Group_Id - User_Username - GroupPermission_Id.  There can be multiple groups, multiple users, multiple permissions.  I have plenty of examples that help me make a single relationship table, but I can't find anything that includes multiple relationships.

Here are my entities...

User:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, StringLength(EntityLength.UsernameLength)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(EntityLength.NameLength)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(EntityLength.NameLength)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(EntityLength.Email)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPermission UserPermission { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupPermission> GroupPermissions { get; set; } 

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + ' ' + LastName; }
    }
}
```

Group:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(EntityLength.GenericLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(EntityLength.DescriptionLength)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupPermission> GroupPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

GroupPermission:

```
public class GroupPermission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(EntityLength.GenericLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public enum Permission
    {
        Leader = 1,
        Editor = 2,
        User = 3
    }
}
```

When the tables are created using this structure, I get a GroupPermissions table that has Id, Name, GroupId, and UserId.  This table needs to only be Id and Name.  Then it creates a GroupPermissionUsers table that holds GroupPermissions_Id and User_Username.  This is the table that should be Id, Group_Id, User_Username, GroupPermission_Id.

Does anybody have any tips to accomplish this or am I thinking about the design of this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such case you are missing additional entity. It should look like:

New `Permission` entity with `Id` and `Name`:

```
public class Permission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(EntityLength.GenericLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupPermission> GroupPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Modified `GroupPermission` entity to form junction table among `Users`, `Groups` and `Permissions`:

```
public class GroupPermission
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserName")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wrote this exact (to the letter) solution into my project as you submitted this and it seems to be working.  I was trying to do this without the extra entity thinking that it could be done and I was wrong.  Thank you for confirming my suspicions.  I thought I was missing something but it took me multiple google searches and a weekend to have it hit me.